# Is it possible do create Java classes from JavaDoc?

Tags: java, jar, reverse-engineering, javadoc

Here is the problem: Currently my team work for a vendor, that provided us a huge JavaDoc spec from their library, but did not provide the .jar file with stubs or implementation.

We already talked to them, but they will provide the .jar files only in 2 to 3 weeks from now. I would not like to wait this time to start our development, so here's the question:

Given JavaDoc .html files only, are there any tools (free / open source) available so we could create a .jar (or a bunch of .java/.class files) that would enable us to compile our code?

Comment: I would work towards terminating any cooperation with such a vendor ASAP.

Comment: Was the javadoc produced with `-linksource`?  http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/solaris/javadoc.html#linksource

Comment: @Michael Borgwardt, 100% agreed, but this is another discussion. There are some politics involved not relevant for us at stackoverflow right now. :)

Comment: @Mike Samuel, negative. No line numbers, no private methods exposed.

Comment: @Machado, `-linksource` has nothing to do with line numbers or privateness.  If specified, the source, pretty printed to HTML, is included in the javadoc linked from member definitions.

Comment: @Mike Samuel, thanks for the tip! The link you provided stated that *[-linksource]* _Creates an HTML version of each source file (with line numbers)..._ and _This option exposes all private implementation details..._, so I guess that mislead me. I looked again inside the HTML's, and no pretty printed source there.

Comment: @Machado, understood.  If it had been there, that would've been an easy way to bootstrap your project, but it sucks that it's not.  Good luck with the contract.

Comment: Instead of creating java classes from a javadoc, wouldn't it be better if you just create wrapper / facade classes on top of the vendor's API? That way you can easily mock behavior as well. When they release their API you'll just need to implement your wrapper classes.

Comment: @seibzhen, could be, but the API is too big to just wrap. In this particular case, wrapping what we need would be like rewrite all the classes as proxies, and the cost-benefit analysis is not good.

Answer (score 4):

[doc2java](http://doc2java.berlios.de/) seems to do exactly what you want.

Comment: this seems to be good, but the latest version is from 2004. I'm running those on my html files, but having some exceptions like `java.lang.IllegalStateException: unable to find the start of the documentation defined by [START OF CLASS DATA].`. Do you know if it works with JavaDoc newer than 2004 ?

Comment: Cannot accept this answer, because it does not work for me due to above reason. Anyone could get doc2java working ?

Comment: @Machado - You could :-)  Seriously, if it is this important to you and your company, you should be willing to put in slightly more than a token effort.

Comment: Nice necro. :) As a problem of 2011, I actually did a small doc to java program to solve my problem at that time. The code, however, was single-purpose and was thrown away, since it was not intended to be a broader jack-of-all-trades like doc2java.

Answer (score 0):

codavaj claims to support Java 6 including generics.

http://codavaj.sourceforge.net/

I have not yet tested it.