# Generating code from java doc

Tags: java, javadoc

I have a java document for a huge project.
I need the  classes and interfaces so I can get a project to start with. 
Are there any tools available which parse java document and generate  java files so I can start writing the logic.
It will be better if it can be done using command prompt.

Edit:
I don't have code. Problem is this is a part of specification between user of the application and library writer.
BTW thanks for answers. It seems like no such tool exists.

Comment: The question aside, what happened to code which was used to generate this Javadoc from?

Comment: Do you have code or javadoc documentation? At any rate, I'd suggest using an IDE like Eclipse rather than the command line.

Comment: Your question is not really clear - if you want to generate Source code from the JavaDoc output, then it is a duplicate of [Is it possible do create Java classes from JavaDoc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871308/is-it-possible-do-create-java-classes-from-javadoc) (and the answer is "it looks like there is no such tool"). Anyway, why doesn't the one who generated the JavaDoc can give you the sources, too?

Comment: Are the Javadocs created by hand, and not from some source code? Strange. (Don't make any contracts with people who can give you JavaDoc but not the source code used to generate it. This just hinders the progress.)

Answer (score 2):

Give this document a read:

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-2000/jw-0818-javadoc.html

They write a code generator using javadoc and the doclet API.

Comment: I don't think this is the right solution here - to use a Javadoc doclet, you already need some Java source code written, it will not run on a HTML file (if I didn't miss some recent development).

Comment: Agreed. You have to at least put in the minimum, like the interfaces first, with javadoc comments, then generate from there.  Either way, the interface needs to be specified to have some information to generate the domain model from. I latched onto the "java document" wording used in the question.  I have a generator that generates model, persistence, and ui sources from a json specification.  I have not yet posted this to github.  I will let you know when I have.